# how to clean RAM programmatically cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

In RAM , having four type (wired memory , active memory, non-active memory, free memory)

i have fetched the value of this four type memory. but i want to clear RAM through. how it can be possible to clear RAM programmatically in objective-c?

**here is some of code:**

```
#import <sys/sysctl.h>
#import <mach/host_info.h>
#import <mach/mach_host.h>
#import <mach/task_info.h>
#import <mach/task.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"




@interface AppDelegate ()

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSView *myview ,*view2;

@end

@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize myview;
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    int mib[6];
    mib[0] = CTL_HW;
    mib[1] = HW_PAGESIZE;

    int pagesize;
    size_t length;
    length = sizeof (pagesize);
    if (sysctl (mib, 2, &pagesize, &length, NULL, 0) < 0)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "getting page size");
    }

    mach_msg_type_number_t count = HOST_VM_INFO_COUNT;

    vm_statistics_data_t vmstat;
    if (host_statistics (mach_host_self (), HOST_VM_INFO, (host_info_t) &vmstat, &count) != KERN_SUCCESS)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Failed to get VM statistics.");
    }

//    double total = vmstat.wire_count + vmstat.active_count + vmstat.inactive_count + vmstat.free_count;
  //  double wired = vmstat.wire_count / total;
  //  double active = vmstat.active_count / total;
  //  double inactive = vmstat.inactive_count / total;
  //  double free = vmstat.free_count / total;

    task_basic_info_64_data_t info;
    unsigned size = sizeof (info);
    task_info (mach_task_self (), TASK_BASIC_INFO_64, (task_info_t) &info, &size);

    double unit = 1024 * 1024;
  //
  //  NSString *resultstring = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"% 3.1f MB\n% 3.1f MB\n% 3.1f MB", vmstat.free_count * pagesize / unit, (vmstat.free_count + vmstat.inactive_count) * pagesize / unit, info.resident_size / unit];    NSLog(@"%fGB",total);


    NSLog(@"Free :% 3.1fMB",vmstat.free_count * pagesize / unit);
    NSLog(@"wired :% 3.1fMB",vmstat.wire_count * pagesize / unit);
    NSLog(@"active :% 3.1fMB",vmstat.active_count * pagesize / unit);
    NSLog(@"inactive :% 3.1fMB",vmstat.inactive_count * pagesize / unit);
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  Most of that memory can only be cleared by killing every other process running on the system.  That's not a very practical thing to do.  The majority of the remainder will be used by OS caches, and there's not much you can do to affect those, even if you had a valid reason to do so.

Comment: If your process is root, then `execl("/sbin/shutdown", "shutdown", "now");` will clear all RAM for you. If you're looking for something else, what do you mean by "clear RAM?"

Comment: i m creating an app like  memory cleaner, so i want to do programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

to implement an app like memory cleaner: just alloc as much memory as possible.  the other apps will get memory pressure notifications and OS X will try to free as much for your app. you then release the just allocated memory leaving free memory.

Comment: @prince  did you find a solution to clean memory in any other way to what I described? Have you had a look at the "Memory Clean" app from Mac App Store and checked with Activity Monitor what it does?